# Como saber Exactamente las lineas de un jlist en java?

Tags: java

como dije en otra pregunta respondida tengo un jlist que utilizo como contador de lineas y funciona bien pero ahora el problema esta aqui al abrir un archivo cualquiera me cuenta todas las lineas bien pero empezando desde 2 enves de 1 puse que me escriba tambien en la consola y en en la consola escribe bien desde 1 pero no entiendo por que no hace lo mismo en la lista. Parte de mi codigo aqui

```js
        String archivo=new String(rutas.getText()); //obtiene el texto de la ruta especificada       
        File archivos = new File(archivo);
        editor.setText(null);
        int lotos = texto;//obtiene las lineas del archivo anterior
        int lineas = 0;//especifico las lineas desde 0
        try {
        BufferedReader leer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(archivo));
        String linea = leer.readLine();
        while (linea != null) {
            modelolista.remove(modelolista.size() -lotos);//resto las lineas del anterior archivo
            editor.append(linea+"\n");
            linea = leer.readLine();
            lineas++;//incremento asta llegar a la ultima linea
            modelolista.addElement(lineas);//añade las lineas incrementadas
            System.out.println(lineas);//imprime en la consola las lineas
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ed.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi sugerencia es que desacoples tu codigo. Todo lo tienes junto y mezclado. Usa este código para leer tu archivo de texto y en otro algoritmo ingresa las lineas de interés`

```
  public Stream<String> leerAchivoExterno(String rutaArchivo) {
    Stream<String> lineas = null;

    try {
        lineas = Files.lines(Paths.get(rutaArchivo), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ArchivoImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return lineas;
}`.
```

Luego puedes aplicar este algoritmo para mostrar los valores extraídos del archivo y cualquier otra operación de interés.

```
// listaGrafica es un javax.swing.JList<String>
    Stream<String> lineas = Stream.of("avion","carro"); // Aqui va el algoritmo que lee las lineas del archivo. Pero por simplicidad agregue manualmente los valores
    DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel(); // Se crea una variable que almacene los valores de interés especializados para los jlist

    lineas.forEach(dlm::addElement); // se agrega cada valor
    listaGrafica.setModel(dlm); // y el modelo se le agrega al jlist

 // A partir de aqui solo muestro los valores. Puedes mejorarlo según tus requerimientos.
    System.out.println("lineas: "+listaGrafica.getModel().getSize());
    IntStream.range(0, listaGrafica.getModel().getSize())
             .forEach(indice ->{
                 System.out.println("linea = ("+indice+") valor = "+listaGrafica.getModel().getElementAt(indice));
             });
```